# How do I factor integers using Perl?

Tags: perl, integer, factors

I want split integers into their factors. For example, if the total number of records is:

```
169 - ( 13 x 13 times) 
146 - ( 73 x 2 times) 
150 - ( 50 x 3 times)
175 - ( 25 x 7 times)
168 - ( 84 x 2 ) 
160 - ( 80 x 2 times)
```

When it's more than 10k - I want everything on 1000 
When it's more than 100k - I want everything on 10k

In this way I want to factor the number. How to achieve this? Is there any Perl module available for these kinds of number operations?

Suppose total number of records is 10k. It should be split by 1000x10 times only; not by 100 or 10s.

I can use `sqrt` function. But it's not always what I am expecting. If I give the input 146, I have to get (73, 2).

Comment: OP has a lot of spelling/grammatical errors.

Comment: I have changed and fixed some what .

Comment: 12 x 12 = 144. Is 146 intentional?

Comment: The examples seemed to follow a pretty clear pattern until the 10k one on the end: 
1) If N is within some delta of a square number, use that. 
2) Failing that, use (smallest prime factor) * (N/smallest prime factor)

But the 10k should be 10x1000 example doesn't fit because that should be 100x100.  What specific patterns are you hoping to fit

Comment: Why is is 146 = (12 x 12) and not (2 x 73) ?

Comment: You need to further explain this question to get a good answer.

Given an integer as input, what is the output that you want?

Comment: oops, in #2 in my comment that should have been "small prime fator" instead of "smallest" but even that doesn't make a lot of sense because there's no way of gauging it.

Comment: This sounds like he's trying to page output, or generate dynamic tables or data files. He doesn't want them too wide to promote readability, but he also doesn't want the last, partial page/table/file to be significantly different. With the 146 example, he may be able to discard the last few if there aren't that many.

Comment: The question is unclear.  Perhaps stating the goal would help in making sense of this.

Comment: This question needs the "homework" tag.

Comment: Google "perl number factor". Try that before asking any question so you learn how to answer your own questions.

Comment: My Question is different and some changed question into different one .. Please edit question with out any change the original

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same algorithms you find for other languages in Perl. There isn't any Perl special magic in the ideas. It's just the implementation, and for something like this problem, it's probably going to look very similar to the implementation in any language.

What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe we can point you at the right algorithm if we know what you are trying to do:

- Why must numbers over 10,000 use the 1,000 factor? Most numbers won't have a 1,000 factor.
- Do you want all the factors, or just the largest and its companion?
- What do you mean that the sqrt function doesn't work as you expect? If you're following the common algorithm, you just need to iterate up to the floor of the square root to test for factors. Most integers don't have an integral square root.

Answer (score 2):

If the number is not a prime you can use a factoring algorithm.

There is an example of such a function here: http://www.classhelper.org/articles/perl-by-example-factoring-numbers/factoring-numbers-with-perl.shtml

Comment: Even if a number is prime you can use a factoring algorithm. You just don't get any additional factors. :)

Comment: That is true, but then the result would just be 1 x N, which I thought is not too useful to the original poster :).

Answer (score 1):

Loop through some common numbers in an acceptable range (say, 9 to 15), compute the remainder modulo your test number, and choose the lowest.

```
sub compute_width {
    my ($total_records) = @_;
    my %remainders;
    for(my $width = 9; $width <= 15; $width += 1) {
      my $remainder = $total_records % $width;
      $remainders{$width} = $remainder;
    }
    my @widths = sort { 
      $remainders{$a} <=> $remainders{$b} || 
      $a <=> $b 
    } keys %remainders;
    return $widths[0];
}
```